# Error message: `}' expected but eof found.,

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

```
    import play.*;
    import play.mvc.*;
    import play.data.*;
    import play.data.Form.*;
    import views.html.*;
    import models.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;


    public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result index() 
    {
    List members = Member.findAll();
    return ok(index.render(members,               Staff.getLoggedIn(session().get("staff_id")));
    }

    @Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
    public Result addMember()
    {
    Form addMemberForm = Form.form(Member.class);
    return ok(addMember.render(addMemberForm,Staff.getLoggedIn(session().get("staff_id"))));
    }
    @Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
    public Result addMemberSubmit() 
    {
    Form newMemberForm = Form.form(Member.class).bindFromRequest();

    if(newMemberForm.hasErrors()){
    return badRequest(addMember.render(newMemberForm, Staff.getLoggedIn(session().get("staff_id"))));
    }
    newMemberForm.get().save();
    flash("success","Member" + newMemberForm.get().name +"has been created");

    return redirect("/");
    }
    @Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
    public Result deleteMember(Long id)
    {
    Member.find.ref(id).delete();
    flash("success", "Member has been deleted");
    return redirect("/");

    }
    @Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
    public Result updateMember(Long id)
    {
    Form memberForm = Form.form(Member.class).fill(Member.find.byId(id));
    return ok(updateMember.render(id, memberForm,Staff.getLoggedIn(session().get("staff_id"))));    
    }
    @Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
    public Result updateMemberSubmit(Long id)
    {
    Form updateMemberForm = Form.form(Member.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(updateMemberForm.hasErrors())
    {
    return badRequest(updateMember.render(id, updateMemberForm, Staff.getLoggedIn(session().get("staff_id"))));
    }

    Member m = updateMemberForm.get();
    m.id = id;
    m.update();
    flash("Success", "Member "+updateMemberForm.get().name + " has been updated");
    return redirect("/");

    }

    public Result login(){
    return ok(login.render(Form.form(Login.class),Staff.getLoggedIn(session().get("staff_id"))));
    }

    public Result logout(){
    session().clear();
    flash("Success", "You've been logged out");
    return redirect(routes.Application.login());
    }

    public Result authenticate(){
    Form loginForm = Form.form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();

    if(loginForm.hasErrors()){
    return badRequest(login.render(loginForm,Staff.getLoggedIn(session().get("staff_id"))));
    }
    else{
    session().clear();
    session("email", loginForm.get().username);
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }

    }
    }
```

this is the error i am getting,

```
`}' expected but eof found.
```

Comment: Staff.getLoggedIn(session().get("staff_id"))); should be four closing brackets. )))); solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used four closing brackets in the below method:

```
public Result index() 
{
    List members = Member.findAll();
    return ok(index.render(members, Staff.getLoggedIn(session().get("staff_id")));
}
```

I added one more `)` to the end of `ok(index.render(members, Staff.getLoggedIn(session().get("staff_id")))`